# issue with zend form element displaying

Tags: zend-framework

Please check the code below, 
the problem is that no form element are displayed in test action 
not able to locate

Test.php-->Form Class

```
class Application_Form_Test extends Zend_Form
    {
        public $T_FILEUP;
        public $T_SUBMIT;
        /*function init 
         * initialise all the elements
         * */
        public function _init()
        {
            $this->T_FILEUP=new Zend_Form_Element_Text('image');
            //$this->T_FILEUP->setDestination(UPLOADS);

            $this->T_SUBMIT=new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('add');



        }
        /*function to generate a form for specific function
         * */
        public function generateForm()
        {
            return $this->addElements(array($this->T_FILEUP,$this->T_SUBMIT));
        }

    }
```

### TestAction

```
public function testAction()
    {
        $objForm=new Application_Form_Test();
        $forms=$objForm->generateForm();
        $this->view->form=$forms;
  }
```

test.phtml

```
<?php 
//echo $this->nm;
echo $this->form->image;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function name for the hook is wrong (no "_"):

use:

```
        public function init()
        {
            $this->T_FILEUP=new Zend_Form_Element_Text('image');
            //$this->T_FILEUP->setDestination(UPLOADS);

            $this->T_SUBMIT=new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('add');     

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not generated because `_init()` method is not exectuted. I believe that you wanted to use `init()` rather that `_init()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify because I've had this same issue.

**Bootstrap.php**
`_initXXXXX()`

**Controllers** and **Forms**
`init()`

Subtle difference, but it will cause you to bang your head on a wall if you don't catch it.